# Howto measure action execution time in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I am looking for a way to measure the execution times of all my actions in my JSF application.

A hacky solution I found so far is to extend *com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl*, overwrite *processAction*, and call *super.processAction* in my implementation:

```
public class MyActionListener extends ActionListenerImpl {

            public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws FacesException {
                   watch.start();
                    super.processAction(event);
                   watch.stop();
            }
}
```

Then I add my own ActionListener implementation to faces config:

```
<application>
        <action-listener>MyActionListener</action-listener>
</application
```

But this adds a dependency on jsf-impl and is hacky. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked best was to implement a ServletContextListener, implement contextInitialized, create a reflection proxy for the current default action listener and measure the time in the proxy's invocation handler.

```
@Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // get JSF application factory
        ApplicationFactory applicationFactory = (ApplicationFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.APPLICATION_FACTORY);
        Application application = applicationFactory.getApplication();
        ActionListener defaultActionListener = application.getActionListener();

        // create proxy for the default actionlistener
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        ActionListenerInvocationHandler actionListenerInvocationHandler = new ActionListenerInvocationHandler(defaultActionListener);
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] interfaces = new Class[] { ActionListener.class };
        ActionListener actionListenerProxy = (ActionListener) Proxy.newProxyInstance(contextClassLoader, interfaces, actionListenerInvocationHandler);

        // set proxied actionListener as new default actionlistener
        application.setActionListener(actionListenerProxy);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) instead and hook on [`PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html#INVOKE_APPLICATION).

```
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION;
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        watch.start();
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        watch.stop();
    }

}
```

Register it as `<phase-listener>` instead.

Note, I understand that your code is pseudo, but for the sake of completeness I would like to warn you that you need to realize that the very same single instance of the listener is shared among all threads/requests. You'd rather like to store the `watch` in the request map and definitely not as an instance variable.